# Alternative to Webbrowser control

Tags: firefox, activex, browser

Has anyone found and used an alternative to the Microsoft Webbroswer ActiveX control with any success? The open source Firefox ActiveX version seems to be a dead project development wise and based on an old Firefox version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look to the [GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) Project, an open-source component for embedding Mozilla Gecko (Firefox) in .NET applications.

> Written in clean, fully commented C#,
>   GeckoFX is the perfect replacement for
>   the default Internet Explorer-based
>   WebBrowser control.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://geckofx.googlecode.com/files/geckofx-screenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: I've noticed a long startup cost to using the stock WebBrowserControl.  does GeckoFX start up faster?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Microsoft's WebView2 NuGet Package named "Microsoft.Web.WebView2" and dropped the control on a Windows Form and gave it a source to navigate to:

```
//Build your own URL
string sURL = $"https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri={sCallbackURLEncoded}&client_id={sConsumerKey}%40AMER.OAUTHAP";
//Set it as the source
wvLogin.Source = new Uri(sURL);
```

BAM! It worked. I wish I had known this was available before wasting time on browser controls that do not package well or testing browsers that cost $800 or $1500 for a single licencse.