# Scraping data, loading scripts

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Lately I'm trying to scrap some data from the web page using C#. 
My problem is, that in C# when I'm using `WebBrowser` object to manipulate with the web page, when I navigate to my web page in body I only get:

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript"   src="com.astron.kapar.WebClient/com.astron.kapar.WebClient.nocache.js"></script>
</body>
```

But if you go on actual web page https://kapalk1.mavir.hu/kapar/lt-publication.jsp?locale=en_GB and look the source you see there is some tables in body probably because browser loads scripts.

My question is, What is the way in C# to manipulate or deal with that kind of web page? For example to choose some dates and get some data? Is there any good library?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: I believe that a possible explanation is that the website filters for user agent and returns to you a different content whether you are using browser or not. I don't have `WebBrowser` API at hand but may you try to fool the `User-Agent` header to see what it returns?

Comment: Update: no, it's like that. I opened with Firefox and looked at the source with CTRL+U and found the very same within the body. The Javascript generates the HTML on load, and is also minified (which means partially obfuscated). You may want to reverse engineer their APIs and make meaningful requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either headless IE, or headless WebKit.

These questions might also be relevant.

[Headless browser for C# (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net)

[c# headless browser with javascript support for crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254817/c-sharp-headless-browser-with-javascript-support-for-crawler)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `javascript`, one good solution for scrapping javascript-driven site would be [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/).

I find `casperjs` really easy to work with for scrapping javascript-heavy site.

1. Write a `casperjs script` to scrap the site with `css selectors` and send your desired output as `JSON` to `stdout` using `JSON.Stringify`.
2. Invoke `casperjs` from `C#` using `ProcessStartInfo`. Read from `stdout` and serialize the `json` back to `POCO`.