# C# Collecting data from website after scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, forms

I want to download some code from an HTML website but the data that I need appears after the JavaScript loads (as i know). I tried WebClient but this gets only the HTML code without any JS changes and as far I know there is nothing more I can do. Now I'm trying WebBrowser in WPF and Forms. I have WebBrowser control and I'm navigating to my url address but I'm getting JS errors and scripts are still not loading.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.polskieszlaki.pl/atrakcje/woj-slaskie/"));
```

How to get webpage fully loaded with all scripts?

Btw. I don't need a web browser, I just need to collect some data so the HTML code after scripts are loaded is enough for me.

Comment: I don't have experience with this myself, but you want a headless browser. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254817/c-sharp-headless-browser-with-javascript-support-for-crawler

Comment: It was kinda tricky to find some elements and maybe it's not fast solution but it works and i collect all data what i want. Thanks!