# WebBrowser Read Viewer code and not Source Code

Tags: c#, php

I have this code on php document

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write( geoip_city() );
      </script>' ?>
```

after open in browser it returns your city name but on

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string client2 = client.DownloadString("http://www.mywebsite/ip2.php");

            MessageBox.Show(client2);
```

it returns the source code. Why does this happen?

I am using [this script for geolocation.](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/)

Comment: Perhaps your server is not setup to parse PHP?  Try creating a single script that looks like this: "<? phpinfo(); ?>" and open it on your browser.  If it shows a long list of information about your PHP setup, then this isn't the issue.  If it just shows "<? phpinfo(); ?>" in the browser, then your web server isn't interpreting, and it'd be a web server configuration issue.

Comment: You need to download the file from the live server. If it is hosted on the same computer, you need to use `client.DownloadString("127.0.0.1/mydocument/ip2.php");` Make sure you have PHP setup properly too.

Comment: the file is on server with php and code work but in c# after download string return only source code

Comment: WebClient does not runs javascript code see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372277/webclient-runs-javascript

Comment: i have tested with webbrowser.

webbrowser.navigate("http//www.mysite/ip2.php")

string city = webbrowser.Documenttext.Tostring();

retunr always all source code same the webclient

Comment: try a simple script that returns hello world, see if it returns source code, if so, you web server may not be setup properly to handle php as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not have PHP set up correctly on the server.

When you go to the page ( http://www.mywebsite/ip2.php ) does the source code show up there as well? What server software are you running?

Comment: php5 and mysql... on browser the site work, only in c# have problem