# C# - Navigate webpage invisible

Tags: c#

I am trying to navigate the webpage invisibly. I have tried this

```
Navigate2(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") + "\\track.html");
```

It navigates, but it shows the internet explorer window. How can I make it invisible ?

(edit: I dont want to get page content, it should navigate there)

Comment: And you added the C tag - why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can get web page's content and save it into the string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate but neither display nor keep the page content? Just ignore the returned value (based on the duplicate I posted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadString("http://www.gooogle.com");
// or
client.GetWebRequest("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Will it run the js file in the page ?

Comment: It appears that it will not. See this [question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372277/webclient-runs-javascript).

Comment: Hmm. So is there any other way to hide the ie window ?

Comment: Try the [`-embedding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh826025.aspx) flag. I'm not sure if it runs js though.