# VB.net downloadstring needs javascript for my host?

Tags: javascript, php, vb.net

Whenever I use downloadstring like this:

```
   Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()

   Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("http://abstract.ezyro.com/version.php")
```

It always says "This site requires javascript to work", even though there is nothing javascript related. Version.php is as follows:

```
    <?php
    echo "4.2.0-2017/03/02";
    ?>
```

Any help?

Comment: There is probably something on your site itself that checks whether JavaScript is running in the user's browser, and displays a different 'error' page if it's not. As VB.NET doesn't contain JavaScript, the site will think you're not using it.

Comment: Is there any way to support javascript?

Comment: You need a .net compatible headless browser. Something like https://bitbucket.org/RusKnyaz/optimus/wiki/Home

Comment: Take a look as this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5372524/2592875](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5372524/2592875)