# How do I convert my html game into an executable file?

Tags: html, visual-studio, game-development, unreal-engine4

I am having so much difficulty turning my html games into a windows application.

I'm trying to follow this: ( [Converting HTML + JavaScript to an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584589/converting-html-javascript-to-an-exe) )

but I can't find a way to input my html into visual studio. I feel like I'm dumb, but I've tried visual studio, unreal engine, and game maker, but nothing seems straightforward.

Is there an easy way to convert web pages into an application?

Comment: There are links in the accepted answer to that question to other questions explaining every step of the process. It talks about how to use the WebBrowser control to load an external HTML page. You would have had to already created the game already to do that.